# Node.js - Dynamically forbid some public paths on production mode

Tags: node.js, path, public, production, restrict

I'm using node.js with express.js. Here's my public dir structure:

```
public/
    js/
    css/
    images/
    built/
        main-built.js
        main-built.css
    index.html
    dev.html
```

Where `index.html` links to scripts in `js/` and `css/`, while `dev.html` links to `main-built.js` and `main-built.css`. How can I dynamically forbid some paths under `public/`  (`js/*`, `css/*` and `dev.html`) when the app is launched as production mode?

Comment: why do you have files in `public` if they aren't public?

Comment: It just for convenience, for I can use them in development mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Express, you could block them with a small piece of middleware.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      if( /* check req.url for blocked content */) {
        res.send('Access Denied');
      }
    }
    else {
      // Not in production, proceed to next handler.
      next();
    }
  });
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```